# Iterating through a comma separated file of integers to use the chr() function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently in the process of trying to write a piece of code that would allow me to take a file of numbers and be able to use the chr() function to turn the numbers to their Unicode equivalent.

This is what I have so far:

```
readFile = "numbers.txt"
with open(readFile) as f:
   num = f.readlines()
   print(num)

   for x in num[:]:
      x = chr(x)
      print(x)
```

The print(num) gives me this:

```
['35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,46,100,111,45,34,34,34,34,34,39,45,111,46,46,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,10,\n',
```

How would I go about reading each line and then printing them on a new line instead of the same line, as i have several lines like above but they all output on the one line. Furthermore what would be the best approach to get the chr() function to work because when I try to print(x) if get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Ethan/Desktop/EthanWork/Python/Python Projects/Uni 
 Work/asciiNumToChar/Main.py", line 7, in <module>
   x = chr(x)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it a lot and I would appreciate if you never outright told me the answer as I am trying to learn instead if you could point me in the direction to be able to solve it myself I would be very appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Create a list, append those to it and then iterate over it to get the `char` equvi

Comment: It seems that the file only contains one line, where values are seperated by commas, your best bet is to split the num string by commas to get an array of values which you can then iterate

Comment: @RnD Yes, the example her is just one line but what would I have to change if the file was multiple lines. The idea of this piece of software would be to turn ASCII art into number equivalent and back.

Comment: @Effen_ basically, what you're already doing just you have to split your string by commas to get individual values that you could then convert, ```num = num.split(',')```

Comment: Okay thanks, will give it a go now

Comment: @Effen_ did the answer posted below helped? if it did you may mark it: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work cheers

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a `list` to store the values
2. `split` by `,` to get the values separately
3. Convert each `str` in the list to `int`
4. Iterate over the `list` to get the `char` equi

**numbers.txt**:

```
35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,46,100,111,45,34,34,34,34,34,39,45,111,46,46,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,35,10
```

**Hence**:

```
readFile = "numbers.txt"
numList = []

with open(readFile) as f:
   lines = f.readline()
for line in lines.split(","):
   # print(line)
   numList.append(line)

for x in numList:
    print(chr(int(x)))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
#
#
#
#
#
.
.
.
d
o
-
.
.
```

**EDIT (shorter ver)**:

```
readFile = "numbers.txt"
numList = []
chr_list = []

with open(readFile) as f:
   lines = f.readline()
for line in lines.split(","):
   numList.append(line)
   chr_list.append(chr(int(line)))

print(numList)
print(chr_list)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
['35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '46', '100', '111', '45', '34', '34', '34', '34', '34', '39', '45', '111', '46', '46', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '35', '10\n']
['#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '.', 'd', 'o', '-', '"', '"', '"', '"', '"', "'", '-', 'o', '.', '.', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '#', '\n']
```

**EDIT 2**:

If you were to map each value to its `char` eqvui `(key : val)`, probably a `dict` approach would be useful:

```
dict_ = {}
with open(readFile) as f:
   lines = f.readline()
for line in lines.split(","):
   dict_[line] = chr(int(line))

print(dict_)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
{'35': '#', '46': '.', '100': 'd', '111': 'o', '45': '-', '34': '"', '39': "'", '10\n': '\n'}
```

Comment: ```I would appreciate if you never outright told me the answer as I am trying to learn instead if you could point me in the direction to be able to solve it myself I would be very appreciative.```

Comment: He clearly stated that he wanted help by pointing him into the right direction, I guess it's fine now after editing your answer, but before it was plain code.

Comment: @RnD Obviously, I was adding the comments! :D